# SSH tunnel to VNC on a Windows 7 system. Error: Tunnel device open failed

Tags: fedora, windows, vnc, ssh-tunneling, cygwin

The system I'm trying to SSH from is Fedora 20 x86_64. The system tunneling to is Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit and it has Cygwin installed with TigerVNC and OpenSSH.

- VNC is running on Windows 7 on port 2= Host:2
- XWinServer is running on Windows 7 in cygwin.

This works `vncviewer Hostname:2`.

When I run this command:

```
$ ssh -L 5902:localhost:5902 User@HostName -p port
```

I get this error but get connected through SSH to the Windows system:

```
Tunnel device failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding
```

Here is the debug:

```
$ ssh -vvv -L 5902:localhost:5980 UserName@HostName -p Port
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/UserName/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/UserName/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/UserName/.ssh/config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to HostName [HostName] port Port.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 499999 ms remain after connect
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [HostName]:Port
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[HostName]:Port" from file "/home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b5:05:1a:33:1b:44:21:ae:00:37:0f:2b:24:ae:41:26
debug3: put_host_port: [HostName]:Port
debug3: put_host_port: [HostName]:Port
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[HostName]:Port" from file "/home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[192.168.1.69]:34500" from file "/home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[HostName]:34500' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/UserName/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/UserName/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
UserName@HostName's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 68 padlen 12 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to HostName ([192.168.1.69]:34500).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5902 forwarded to remote address localhost:5980
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5902.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5902.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting tun unit 2147483647 in mode 1
debug1: sys_tun_open: failed to configure tunnel (mode 1): Operation not permitted
Tunnel device open failed.
Could not request tunnel forwarding.
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 2
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug2: channel 2: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env DREAL_TECHNO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env VH_PATSFX
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env KDE_MULTIHEAD
debug3: Ignored env TPD_GLOBAL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env DM_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env MBK_IN_PH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env XSCH_PARAM_NAME
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env XDM_MANAGED
debug3: Ignored env GTK2_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env VH_MAXERR
debug3: Ignored env GTK_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env GS_LIB
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env RDS_OUT
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env SHELL_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XFSM_PARAM_NAME
debug3: Ignored env ALLIANCE_TOP
debug3: Ignored env GRAAL_TECHNO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env KDE_FULL_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env TPD_LOCAL
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env MBK_SCALE_X
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env MBK_CATAL_NAME
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=none
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW
debug3: Ignored env MBK_OUT_PH
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KDE_IS_PRELINKED
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_UID
debug3: Ignored env GENVIEW_TECHNO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env RDS_IN
debug3: Ignored env MBK_SPI_MODEL
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env MBK_OUT_LO
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env MBK_VSS
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env VH_BEHSFX
debug3: Ignored env SSH_ASKPASS
debug3: Ignored env GPG_TTY
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_VERSION
debug1: Sending env LANGUAGE = 
debug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MBK_C4_LIB
debug3: Ignored env MBK_VDD
debug3: Ignored env MBK_TARGET_LIB
debug3: Ignored env XCURSOR_THEME
debug3: Ignored env RDS_TECHNO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env VH_DLYSFX
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env MBK_IN_LO
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env MBK_WORK_LIB
debug3: Ignored env XPAT_PARAM_NAME
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env PROFILEHOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env QT_PLUGIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env ELP_TECHNO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env MBK_CATA_LIB
debug3: Ignored env CCACHE_HASHDIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 2: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 2
Last login: Tue Apr 15 07:37:45 2014 from HostName.lan
      ____________________,             ______________________________________
   .QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQL_         |                                      |
 .gQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ__   |                                      |
 gQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ==   |                    _.---.)           |
 QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQF=         |          (^--^)_.-"      `;          |
 QQQQQQQQQ================!            |          ) ee (           |          |
 QQQQQQQQ                              |         (_.__._)         /           |
 QQQQQQQQ                              |           `--',        ,'            |
 QQQQQQQQ     ~"jjj__,                 |            jgs )_|--')_|             |
 QQQQQQQQ       "jjjjjjjjjj___         |                ""'   ""'             |
 QQQQQQQQ        ~jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj__  |                                      |
 QQQQQQQQ        _jjjjjjjjjjjjjj/~~~~  |      The Hippo says: Welcome to      |
 QQQQQQQQ      .{jjjjjjj/~~~~~         |                             _        |
 QQQQQQQQ     .{/~~~~`                 |  ____  _   _   ____  _ _ _ (_) ____  |
 QQQQQQQQ                              | / ___)| | | | / _  || | | || ||  _ \ |
 QQQQQQQQ                              |( (___ | |_| |( (_| || | | || || | | ||
 QQQQQQQQQL_______________,            | \____) \__  | \___ | \___/ |_||_| |_||
 QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQL___       |        (___/  (____|                 |
 4QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ___  |                                      |
 (=QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ====   |       -.-. -.-- --. .-- .. -.        |
   (QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQF=         |______________________________________|


UserName@HostName ~
$
```

Comment: That's not actually `port`, right?

Comment: @mikeserv No I just thought I sometimes posted sensitive information, maybe gone little overboard with the censoring, I'm a newbie

Comment: Totally fine - though the `port` itself is really not so sensitive as much as the `ip`. Still, that's probably not the problem. Does my answer below help?

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks man, I'll see what I can find out from your answer

Comment: Let me know if I've got something wrong. I'll be happy to dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man ssh
```

> **`-L`** [`bind_address`:] `port:host:hostport`
>
> > Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to  the  given host and  port  on the remote side.  This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local side, optionally bound to the specified *bind_address*.  Whenever a connection  is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is made to host port *hostport* from the remote machine.  Port forwardings can also be specified in  the configuration file. IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing the address in square brackets. Only the *superuser* can forward privileged ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance  with the `GatewayPorts` setting.  However, an explicit *bind_address* may be used to bind the connection to a specific address. The *bind_address* of *localhost* indicates that the listening  port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or * indicates that the port should be avail able from all interfaces.

The primary problem here is this:

```
 5902:localhost:5902
```

You can't forward `5902` to `5902` - it already is `5902`. That's why it works when you connect without `ssh` - because it's already served. If you want to forward a local port to another then you do:

```
${FROM_PORT}:localhost:${TO_PORT}
```

If you want to forward a local port to a remote machine you do:

```
${LOCAL_PORT}:${REMOTE_HOST}:${REMOTE_PORT}
```

And the remote machine can then connect with:

```
ssh user@localhost -p ${REMOTE_PORT}
```